# Mongodb upsert doesn't work adding new document

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, mongoose

```
Category.findOneAndUpdate({"_id":category_id},update,{upsert: true},callback);
```

this worked when I am updating categories which have existed id, but not create a new document for. I expect that to happen by using upsert here, but it doesn't work. No error returned.

Comment: Use `Collection.update()` with `upsert: true`.

Comment: @Tushar I saw working example using findOneAndUpdate

Comment: Can you update your question with the schema for `Category` and the contents of `update`?

Answer (score 0):

If your model is something like that:

```
var Category = new Schema({
   categoryid:{
     type: Number,
     unique: true,
     required: true
   },
   category_name:{
     type: String,
     required: true
   }
});
```

#### #possible problem One

```
{ [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "23" at path "_id"]
message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "23" at path "_id"'}
```

**Cause**

```
// query with invalid id
Category.findOneAndUpdate({"_id":"23"},update,{upsert: true},callback);
```

maybe your `_id` is not a valid mongo object id, usually mongoId is 24 character long ( `"v387h39f8538457f3fh09485"` )

#### #possible problem two

```
{ [MongoError: exception: E11000 duplicate key error 
index: test.categories.$categoryid_1 dup key: { : 27 } name: 'MongoError'}
```

**Cause**

on my example model, field `categoryid`  should be unique, so if you try to insert duplicate `categoryid` then error may occur to upsert your document

```
// log the result on callback, check if there is any error
console.log(err || result);
```